# CheckboxList item text CSS

Tags: css, checkboxlist

Below is my CheckboxList. Text is showing below the checkbox.

How can I place the text in line ? Here is my view source code

```
<tr>
            <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblReason_16" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblReason$16" value="02. Form of product order/purchase (POS with immediate delivery, POS with delayed delivery, Mail order, Phone order, Internet order)" /><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblReason_16">02. Form of product order/purchase (POS with immediate delivery, POS with delayed delivery, Mail order, Phone order, Internet order)</label></td>
        </tr>




 <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;" colspan="2">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblReason" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" TextAlign="Right">
    <asp:ListItem>01. Two years of financial statements</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>02. Form of product order/purchase (POS with immediate delivery, POS with delayed delivery, Mail order, Phone order, Internet order)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>03. Delivery timeframe.  If product delivery is not immediate, outline average timeframe between initial product purchase and  delivery of product.  If services are purchased, outline average timeframe between initial order and complete provision of  Service.                      </asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML?

Comment: Hello, I had the image but unable to upload it as I am new here

Comment: No need to post an image, just the HTML rendered to the browser.

Comment: @j08691 How can I do that ?

Comment: Right click the page and view the source to see what gets sent to the browser.

Comment: You should edit the question with the code rather than posting it in a comment.

Comment: try to use white-space:nowrap, to force your td to expand . .

Comment: @GCyrillus Hi, WHite space no wrap is displaying all the text in same line making the page looking awkward. I want to break the text and display from start instead of below checkbox

Comment: okay, i understood you wanted a single line. so you want to see the checkbox behind the label ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I want the text to wrap and display in the next line but I dont want it to start below the checkbox, Instead I want it to start from text above the line

Comment: okay, i left an answer with a demo , if that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

Since checkboxes are inline elements, you can wrap your text in a `<span>` element, which is also an inline element.

As an example:

`<input type="checkbox" /><span>Label</span>`

Comment: hello, I did not get you. Can you please elaborate ?